# sklearn stratified train_test_split the least popular class error

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, split, dataset

I have multilabel dataset (`pd.DataFrame`) which looks like this:
[image]

This is value_counts of flatten `tags` column:

```
101     4450171
86      3933972
45      3468383
0       2801217
46      2621773
         ...   
4681       1000
2923       1000
4580       1000
7569       1000
6955       1000
Length: 7657, dtype: int64
```

Then I use `train_test_split` from `sklearn` with `stratify` argument to split dataset with balanced distribution:

```py
train_df, test_df = train_test_split(
    df,
    test_size=0.02,
    stratify=df["tags"].values,
)
```

And I get this error:

```
ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.
```

Why? I see that the least populated class has 1000 samples. Does it actually compare lists instead of list values? I based on this article: https://keras.io/examples/nlp/multi_label_classification/

Answer (score 1):

As you said, `train_test_split` interprets each list of tags as a label, it doesn't matter what it contains. A sample with tags `[1, 2, 3]` will not be identified the same as a sample with tags `[1, 2]`. Hence, you cannot flatten the `tags` column to check the label counts.

The solution, if you want to keep these labels, is to drop the observations with labels that are not enough represented (e.g., with `value_counts() == 1`. In fact, this is also what they do in the article you linked (see the last code snippet of the "Perform exploratory data analysis" paragraph):

```
# Filtering the rare terms.
arxiv_data_filtered = arxiv_data.groupby("terms").filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```